# Помогите с задачей C++. Дано натуральное число N. Определить, если это возможно, пару x,y таких натуральных чисел, что N = x^2+y^2

Tags: c++, математика, теория-чисел

Задача:
Дано натуральное число N. Определить, если это возможно, пару x,y таких натуральных чисел, что N = x^2+y^2.
Есть главная функция, принимает N, и должна эту N прогнать через функцию coupleXY(int num). Подскажите как эти циклы сделать, что бы они находили x, y, где N = x^2+y^2.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

// Функция которая возвращает такие значения x и y, которые x^2+y^2 = num 
int coupleXY(int num)
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    
    while((pow(x,2) + pow(y,2)) == num)
    {
        while(y<num)
        {
        if( (pow(x,2) + pow(y,2)) == num )
            {
            return x,y;
            }
        y++;
        }

    x++;
    }

    // return x,y;  
}

// Главная функция, принимает N, и вызывает функцию, выводя её результат
int main()
{
    int N, resultX, resultY;
    
    cout << "Set natural number N: ";
    cin >> N;
    resultX, resultY = coupleXY(N);
    cout<<"\nx^2+y^2 = N, if "<<endl;
    cout<<"x = "<<resultX<<endl;
    cout<<"y = "<<resultY<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `return x,y;` - а что ж вы только `y` возвращаете? :) Вы вообще-то учебник читали?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну если просто **починить ваш код, без улучшений**, то для начала вы не можете вернуть два числа `return x, y;` их можно вернуть по ссылке:

```
void coupleXY(int num, int& x, int& y)
```

Потом первый цикл у вас должен идти пока `x^2 + y^2 != num` иначе у вас сразу завершается функция при первой же проверке.

Так же для ограничения `x` нужно добавить условие `&& x < num` в первый цикл.

Внутри 1 цикла перед 2, нужно обнулять `y` для того, чтобы для нового `x` попробовать найти `y`.

И наконец если `x` и `y` будут равны `num`, то это значит, что `x` и `y` найдены не были и лучше будет приравнять их к -1, как сигнал, что они не были найдены.

Вот пример вашего кода:

```
void coupleXY(int num, int& x, int& y)
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;

    while ((pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2)) != num && x < num)
    {
        y = 0;
        while (y < num)
        {
            if ((pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2)) == num)
            {
                return;
            }
            y++;
        }
        x++;
    }
    if (x == num && y == num) {
        x = -1;
        y = -1;
    }
}
```

Вот небольшая оптимизация кода выше:

```
void coupleXY(int num, int& x, int& y)
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    while (temp < num)
    {
        while (temp < num) {
            ++y;
            temp = x * x + y * y;
        }
        if (temp == num)
            return;
        ++x;
        y = 0;
        temp = x * x;
    }
    x = -1;
    y = -1;
}
```

Оптимизация состоит в том, что теперь если мы проходим не пока `x < num` и `y < num`, а пока `x*x + y*y <= num`. Так же лишние операции умножения были убраны.

Comment: А смысл перебора `x` до `num`? До корня - за глаза, а из симметрии задачи - до корня от половины. Да и какой смысл во вложенном цикле?

Comment: @Harry пожалуйста читайте внимательней. "_Ну если просто починить ваш код, без улучшений_". Вы правда думаете, что я так написал просто потому, что не догадываюсь как сделать лучше?

Comment: Спасибо большое, заработало, ещё и узнал как возвращать два числа по ссылкам)

Comment: Просто если вы *учите*, то имеет смысл убирать не только неверный синтаксис, но и учить решать задачи хотя бы на ноготь мизинца оптимальнее, чем самый тупой подход. Это - тоже *обучение*. В том, что вы не дурак, я как-то не сомневаюсь, но почему вы опускаетесь в ответах до уровня спрашивающего без попыток подтянуть его к своему уровню хоть немного - не понимаю... Вы показываете, как правильно держать микроскоп при забивании гвоздей, как не пораниться осколками стекла и т.п. - но не показываете ему молоток...

Comment: @Harry спасибо что разъяснили конечно, но я дал ответ, автору этот ответ помог. У меня нет времени учить кого-то,  когда я сам еще учусь. Но только не учите меня, как давать ответы. Я сам все прекрасно понимаю, но сейчас я решил ответить сухо.

Comment: А оптимизация будет только в том, что перебирать будем не до num, а до корня от num?

Comment: @Павел Ериков, по моим наблюдениям вы очень много времени проводите в SO. Почему у вас нет времени дать несколько разъяснений и  поправок,   мягко говоря не понятно

Comment: @ARHovsepyan как минимум потому что сейчас я сижу на экзамене :)

Answer (score 8):

Обычный перебор выглядит примерно так:

```
pair<int,int> coupleXY(int N)
{
    //for(int x = 0; 2*x*x <= N; ++x)  // Если можно 0
    for(int x = 1; 2*x*x <= N; ++x)    // Если 0 нельзя
    {
        int y = sqrt(N-x*x)+0.5;
        if (x*x+y*y == N) return make_pair(x,y);
    }
    return make_pair(-1,-1); //
}

int main()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    auto v = coupleXY(N);
    if (v.first < 0) cout << "No solutions\n";
    else cout << v.first << "^2 + "
              << v.second << "^2 == " << N << endl;
}
```

Принимаем `x <= y`, тогда понятно, что максимальное значение `x` не может превышать `sqrt(N/2)`. Второе значение искать перебором - долго, смысла нет, проще оценить корень и убедиться, что он [не]подходит.

В С++ возврата сразу двух значений из функции нет, это вам не Go, но можно возвращать их в виде структуры, или стандартного класса `pair`. Можно и через указатели/ссылки, но... ну вот не люблю я этот метод :) То, что делали вы - с запятой - как ни смешно, может компилироваться, но вот семантика тут совершенно иная - почитайте об операторе "запятая"...

Для  ARHovsepyan :)

```
for(int x = 1, z = 1; 2*z <= N; ++x, z+=2*x-1)    // Если 0 нельзя
{
    int y = sqrt(N-z)+0.5;
    if (z+y*y == N) return make_pair(x,y);
}
```

Comment: И  еще тут  нет лишнего вызова pow для расчета квадрата.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan А еще можно вообще на возведении в квадрат сэкономить :) - см. дополнение.

Comment: можно отбросить [некоторые случаи сразу без перебора](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares)

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Ну да, вы правы... но это уже в определенном смысле не программная оптимизация , а оптимизация самого алгоритма :) Которая, впрочем, обычно наиболее существенная.

Comment: где-то вы писали `но и учить решать задачи хотя бы на ноготь мизинца оптимальнее, чем самый тупой подход. Это - тоже обучение.` :)

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Так я и не возражаю :) Что я мог - сделал. Вы можете больше - you are welcome! Покажите, как решать задачу с использованием материала, на который вы ссылаетесь - это ваша находка, ваше решение - напишите его.

Comment: @Harry, не скромничайте, у вас хорошо получается!

Comment: @Harry, ответил - критикуйте!

Answer (score 2):

Простой перебор основанный на формуле `(n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2*n + 1`, корень в цикле не вычисляется, также сразу [отбрасываются варианты для которых нет решения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

std::pair<int,int> coupleXY(int N) {
    if (N & 1 && N % 4 != 1) return std::make_pair(0, 0);
    int x = 2 * (int)std::sqrt(N / 2);
    int y = x;

    for(int diff = N - x * x / 2; x > 0; ++diff) {
        if (diff > 0) {
            y += 2;
            diff -= y;
        } else if (diff < 0) {
            x -= 2;
            diff += x;
        } else {
            return std::make_pair(x / 2, y / 2);
        }
    }

    return std::make_pair(0, 0);
}

int main() {
    int N;
    std::cin >> N;
    auto v = coupleXY(N);
    if (v.first) {
        std::cout << v.first << "^2 + " << v.second << "^2 == " << N << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "No solutions\n";
    }
}
```